# Script not loading - Solution Clear Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, load

I made a script which is working fine on Chrome but doesn't load in Firefox. I tried on another PC, and here it works on Firefox but not in Chrome. Clearing cookies makes the script load again.

What can it be? I don't think its the script since its working.

Comment: It doesn't load at all or is caching and not loading a new version? Also how are you loading the script?

Comment: are you loading your script with the `<script>` tag or inline?

Comment: @LukeStoward Its not loading at all. Just an empty section

Comment: Most likely it's browser cache. On Chrome press F12, click the three dots in the top right corner of the dev tools, click settings, and then check 'disable cache (while DevTools is open)'. Then press F5 to refresh the page; does this fix it?

Comment: @michael Yes but my customers dont know what is wrong. They dont know what to press

Comment: You'll need to add a cache bust to your linked assets in that case. So instead of linking to myscript.js you link to myscript.js?ver=1 and then increment the number as you make changes to it